# No comma between location and year, year in parentheses in case of a journal

Tags: biblatex

question: I need the following entry in the bibliography

> Doe John, Title of Book, Location Year.

or, if it's an article

> Doe John, Title of Article, Journal Volume (Year) pages

I have the following code:

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
        \iffieldundef{location}{%
            \printtext[parens]{%
                \printlist{year}\addspace%
                }}{%
            \printfield{location}\addspace%
            \printlist{year}\addspace%
        }
}
```

however the output for this is:

1. Book:

> Doe John, Title of Book, ( ).

1. Article:

> Doe John, Title of Article Volume (Year).

However, the book should be displayed as follows:

> Doe John, Title of book, Location Year.

Any help appreciated.

MWE (complete):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,headings=normal,headsepline=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=4.5cm,right=4.5cm,top=5.5cm,bottom=5.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nty,style=verbose,isbn=false,url=false,publisher=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{Doe1999,
  author = {John Doe},
  title = {Title of Book},
  publisher = {Kluwer Law International},
  year = {1999},
  volume = {25},
  series = {Series},
  shortauthor = {Doe},
  shorttitle = {Title of Book}
}
\end{filecontents}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand\thesection{§ \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}.}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph})}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\alph{paragraph}\alph{subparagraph})}
\newcommand\thesubsubparagraph{\alph{paragraph}\alph{subparagraph}\alph{subsubparagraph})}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\defbibheading{lit}{\chapter*{Lit}}
\defbibheading{mat}{\chapter*{Mat}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished,shorttitle,journal]{title}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{
                \ifnameundef{shortauthor}
                {
                    \iffieldundef{shorttitle}{%
                    \adddot}{
                    \printtext[parens]{%
                    {cit.}\addspace
                    \printfield{shorttitle}%
                    }\adddot
                    }
                }
                {
                    \iffieldundef{shorttitle}
                    {
                        \printtext[parens]{%
                        {cit.}\addspace
                        \printnames{shortauthor}%
                        }\adddot
                    }
                    {
                        \printtext[parens]{%
                        {cit.}\addspace
                        \printnames{shortauthor}\addcomma\addspace
                        \printfield{shorttitle}%
                        }\adddot
                    }
                }
                }\finentry
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
        \iffieldundef{location}{%
            \printtext[parens]{%
                \printlist{year}\addspace%
                }}{%
            \printlist{location}\addspace%
            \printlist{year}\addspace%
        }
}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{publisher}}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
\ifpunct{\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}}{}
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}
\let\abk\nomenclature%
\makenomenclature
\makeindex
\dedication{\hfill You really reading this shit?}
\author{XYZ}
\title{XYZ}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength\overfullrule{50pt}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\maketitle
\dedication
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand*{\dictumauthorformat}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand*{\dictumrule}{}
\dictum[Winston Churchill]{If you're going through hell, keep going.}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{ubs}{chapter}{Preface}
\chapter*{Vorwort}
\input{Preface}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{ubs}{chapter}{Overview}
\shorttoc{Overview}{1}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{ubs}{chapter}{ToC}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{ubs}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature
\printbibliography[title={Lit},heading=lit,notkeyword=mat]
\printbibliography[title={Mat},heading=mat,keyword=mat]
\mainmatter
Lorem ipsum\footcite[p. 1]{Doe1999}.
\backmatter
\addcontentsline{ubs}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Also, I would be grateful if someone could advice on how to use only the text in the (cit. shortauthor, shorttitle) in the actual footnote..

Comment: Above all else, I would use different bibmacros for book and article entries.

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have tried until now. Include a sample `bib` file with package `filecontents`. Do you use `biblatex`? Which document class? Other relevant packages for the bibliography?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `verbose` style and its variants follow an `authortitle`-style bibliography, which is closely based on the standard style defined in `standard.bbx`.

From this file you can see that the punctuation preceding publication dates are set by a few different bibliography macros, depending on the entry type: `issue+date` for `@article`, `publisher+location+date` for most books, `institution+location+date` for reports and theses, `organization+location+date` for `@misc`, and `location+date` for `@booklet` and `@unpublished`.

In `issue+date` publication dates are already set in parentheses. To remove punctuation before the page reference you can redefine the `\bibpagespunct` command from `biblatex.def` in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{\addspace}{\addcomma\space}}
```

To remove page prefixes (e.g. "p." and "pp.") add:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{page}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
```

The comma preceding the publication date in other entry types can originate from a few different places. For example in `publisher+location+date`:

```
\newbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}% <- HERE
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}% <- OR HERE
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

Same goes for the other `*location+date` macros. To remove the commas change all relevant instances of `\addcomma\space` to `\addspace` in your redefinitions. Otherwise you can use the following dirty trick (at your own risk):

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\setunit{\addspace}\printdate}
```

In all these publications dates, if you are just wanting to print the publication year add the following to your preamble.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \clearfield{day}}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \clearfield{month}%
  \clearfield{day}}
```

Your last request about use of `shortauthor` and `shorttitle` in citations would be better addressed as a new question. It needs to be clarified anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much Audrey! I dug into the bbx files (after finding where they are saved: "..\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex") and with your help it's now working!

Comment: @user19581 No problem. You should avoid editing the source files. You can easily do this by redefining bibliography macros in your document preamble or the configuration file `biblatex.cfg` via `\renewbibmacro` or its starred variant `\renewbibmacro*`. These only work when the macro is defined. So when editing a style-specific macro `<macro>` (defined outside `biblatex.def` or `standard.bbx`), preface the redefinition in `biblatex.cfg` with `\providebibmacro{<macro>}{}` or `\providebibmacro*{<macro>}{}`.